# Picking 1st-level spells for a Druid

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-creation, druid

I wanted to pick *Animal Friendship* and *Speak with Animals*.

However, this character has +6 Animal Handling & +4 Nature, so I don't think I need animal handling spells. For this reason, I'm considering *Charm Person* and *Thunderwave*. Is this a good idea?

Which two first-level spells should I pick for my Druid?

Comment: Hi Piano Girl, this question is very much a matter of opinion. Which spells do *you* want to take for *your* Druid?

Comment: I mean...I don't know if it makes much sense to go for Animal Friendship and Speak with Animals...or to pick something else.  Maybe those two, or Charm Person and Thunderwave.

Comment: While it could be difficult to change this question to *not* be almost exclusively opinion based, consider trying to give a party role that you want to perform. Try to be as detailed about your character's personality or motivations or even the mechanics that you want to use the most. That way, there might be an answer.

Comment: Or to ask it another way, what do you want to do with your spells?

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense to go for Animal Frienship or Speak with Animals?

Comment: Since it seems like there might be some confusion between spells known and spells prepared and spells cast this question might be helpful to look at (the druid work pretty much like the cleric when it comes to how their spellcasting works, just with a different spell list): https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44400/how-does-wizard-cleric-spell-preparation-and-casting-work

Comment: I thought maybe because I have plus 6 with Animal Handling, and plus 4 with Nature, why use more animal spells when I can pick a different one?

Comment: I suggest you take it to [chat], really. This question won't likely get re-opened, but you can chat about it with the regulars :)

Answer (score 9):

## You don't have to pick

Druids get access to all their spells and can swap out prepared spells after a long rest.

**You almost certainly get more than 2 spells**

The number they can prepare is equal to their Druid level plus their Wisdom modifier. So with a starting Wisdom modifier of +3, for example, you can prepare four -- not two -- Druid spells.